# Why am i getting " NameError: name 'df2' is not defined" error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hello I separated a large 24-hours DataFrame because each hour includes data more than 500 for three columns and I want to merge the hour data side by side like this :
[image]

Actually all of them come from same dataframe but I separated.Here is my code :

```
...
grouped = dataframeone.groupby(dataframeone.Hour)
df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15,df16,df17,df18,df19,df20,df21,df22,df23,df24,df25]
df_list[0] = grouped.get_group(0)
df_list[0] = df_list[0].drop(columns=['Hour'])


for j in range (1,24): 
        df_list[j] = grouped.get_group(j)  
        df_list[j]= df_list[j].drop(columns=['Hour'])
        df= pd.concat([df_list[j-1],df_list[j]], axis=1)
        print(df)
```

But I am getting this error :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-ff832fd92e63> in <module>
    
     24 grouped = dataframeone.groupby(dataframeone.Hour)
---> 25 df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15,df16,df17,df18,df19,df20,df21,df22,df23,df24,df25]
     26 df_list[0] = grouped.get_group(0)
     27 df_list[0] = df_list[0].drop(columns=['Hour'])

NameError: name 'df2' is not defined
```

I can't understand that the error comes from where and why.. Please show me. How can I fix ? Should I use another way?

Comment: Obviously `df2` doesn't actually exist. How are you creating it?

Comment: in the for loop like this : the loop starts as ` df_list[j] => df_list[1] => df2 = grouped.get_group(1) ...`                                                                                             
  when the loop starts the df_list[j] is taking a value as df2 and it is created at this part.

Comment: Put your creation code in your question.

Comment: Show us how u created it, it doesn't seem to exist in the code you shared

Comment: I don't know I think it is created like this. Am I wrong ?

Comment: As the error message your received clearly indicates, line 25 yields the error, which is: `df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15,df16,df17,df18,df19,df20,df21,df22,df23,df24,df25]`. You, however, have not provided the part of the code, where `df1` - `df25` have been created. Hence, we cannot tell what is wrong with `df2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this because you do not create df2 anywhere. You might do this:

```
...
grouped = dataframeone.groupby(dataframeone.Hour)
df_list = ['df'+str(i) for i in range(1,26)]
df_list[0] = grouped.get_group(0)
df_list[0] = df_list[0].drop(columns=['Hour'])


for j in range (1,24): 
        df_list[j] = grouped.get_group(j)  
        df_list[j]= df_list[j].drop(columns=['Hour'])
        df= pd.concat([df_list[j-1],df_list[j]], axis=1)
        print(df)
```